# How to add google analytics in youtube video?

Tags: video, youtube, google-analytics

I have a website with the following embed:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe id="video-markets" class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/txFhtgO7-28?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
</div>
```

I'm trying to collect the events when you click on 'play', 'pause' and when it reaches the 'end of the video.' For so I am adding the following API that youtube itself provides:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.datagro.com.br/datagro-markets/js/iframe_api.js";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Then make the call events via js:

```
var pauseFlag = false;
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Video', 'Play', 'Video Play']);
            pauseFlag = true;
        }
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED && pauseFlag) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Video', 'Pause', 'Video Pause']);
            pauseFlag = false;
        }
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Video', 'Finished', 'Video Visualizado']);
        }
    }
```

But I can not register my events in google analytics. The problem pertains only to the video, because I can record the others links `<a>` and measure site statistics.

One detail that I noticed while using a debugger, is that the following error appears, do not know if that has something to do:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [...] No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Could anyone help me figure out why I can not register clicks on the video, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe url must include a `&origin=http://example.com` for the iframe to allow you to listen to the player events.